# Parsing Error: Unexpected Token Error

Tags: jquery

I'm new to using jQuery so it's likely something simple I've missed, but I've been unable to figure out what exactly is going wrong with my code. On line 21 where it starts with the `error:` function, I'm getting an unexpected token error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add-user').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventionDefault();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();

        $ajax({
            url: "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/master/collections/users?apiKey=ILEFx3JOAmBpS09IGMajQuSvmRTH_HIY",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 
                "name": name,
                "email": email,
                "password": password
            }),
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",

            success: function(data){
                window.location.href="index.html"
            }
            error: function(xhr, status, err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You're missing a comma in `}
        error: `. Should be `},
        error: `

Comment: It's also `$.ajax`, not `$ajax`, and you should remove the `JSON.stringify` - just give `data` an object and jQuery will serialise it for you based on the specified `contentType`

Comment: Ah, thank you! I knew it was something simple I was missing. Code is now perfectly!